# UIWebView behaviour with maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in my application that loads a mobile website. The mobile website then has lots of different links.

One of those links will try and load a map using Google Maps.

Initially, I had a problem where the user clicked the maps link, as the application would try to load the maps inside my webview. What this does, is make the user stuck, as once you've loaded maps inside the webview, there's no way to go back.

[image]

The only way for you to the go back, is by force closing the application, so not ideal.

I then found other people having the same problem, and implemented the solution as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680096/279395).

This worked great, and now upon clicking the map link, it opens up the maps application. In order to go back to the original application, I can simply double tap the home button, and select my application on the list of running applications.

However, this brought another problem. When I select my application again, it briefly displays the contents back, and then opens the following popup:

[image]

No matter what you chose there, it then loads up the maps again, but inside of the webview this time, which negates all the work done as described previously.

Has anyone here seen this kind of behaviour, and if so, do you know how to go around it, so it doesn't even open the popup asking for your current location?

**UPDATE**
Adding the code I;m using to handle it

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    // URL Starts with "http://maps?"
    if([[request.URL description] hasPrefix:@"http://maps"]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    // otherwise let the webview deal with the request
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your additional comments below, i've edited this answer to focus on the second solution i had originally proposed:

- in one app that i have, in which i go to visit external web sites, in my storyboard, i have created a view containing a UIWebView and a UIButton that is a back button.  you could do this and just have the UIWebView load the map as you would like and go from there.

the .xib would look something like the following … paying special attention to the fact that the **done** button is last in the subview order so that it can sit on top of the webview if desired (yes, the webview could be made to take up 100% of the superview real estate, and the button could sit on top of it; it just does not in this example app i used) (and ignore the background image; in the example app i used to take this screenshot, it is used behind a partially transparent webview; if this is desired, make sure it appears first in the subview order of the .xib view so that it is "behind" all other subviews).

[image]

and the code you would need for this would be in the view controller associated with this .xib, and would look something like the following:

```
@interface WebGoogleMapInUIWebViewViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) int backCount;

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_4_3
@property (readonly, weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
#else
@property (readonly, unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
#endif
@end

@implementation WebGoogleMapInUIWebViewViewController

@synthesize webView;

// … UIViewController life-cycle code and all other code goes here …    

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    if (self.webView.canGoBack) // relying on false for a nil webView
        [self.webView goBack];
}

@end
```

this solution should allow you to stay inside of your app, and then if you do get to the dialog asking for the location, the result should be immediate and apply back only inside of your app.

i know this doesn't solve the problem the way you've stated it, but it might give you the behavior you want.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you mean here. My application is a mobile website, that loads Google maps, so I wouldn't wanna have to change the mobile website. I could change the mobile app though, but could you please exemplify it a bit here?

Comment: in this case, then, you would probably be better off with the second choice: in your the view-controller in your code (or storyboard or xib) where you have the `UIWebView` that you mentioned, you can also have a button of your choosing; placing it last in the order will make it appear visible "on top of" your webview. then, in code, in the previously mentioned view-controller, implement an IBAction for that button that will call `[webView goBack]`. thus, when the user is ready to leave the map, they can hit the back button you've provided, and end up on your original mobile website webView.

Comment: That sounds like the right way to go. Would you be able to provide me with an example of how this might be accomplished? I mean, I've got an idea, but as I said, I'm not really an IoS developer, and having an example here would probably be helpful to other too.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I have not implemented this yet, but from I I read, it seems spot on. You get the bounty :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you definitely returning `NO` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`? when the maps application opens? It sounds to me like the maps application is opening and the method is returning `YES`.

```
if ([[request.URL description] hasPrefix:@"http://maps"]) {
    // open URL in Safari and return NO to prevent UIWebView from load it
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I am 100% returning NO. I've posted my code on the question so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with SurfDev, it sounds like the method is returning YES.  If not, then there isn't really an answer anyone can give you based on the data you've provided.

Personally, I would NSLog each URL the WebView tries to go to.  My *best* guess would be that somehow a 2nd attempt to get to the maps site fires off, and this time the URL is slightly different.

Bottom line is, NSLog to get more data about what the webview is doing.  You can use every one of its callback statements if you have to.